# Zip download issue in php

Tags: php, download, zip

```html
if(isset($_REQUEST['create_all']))
{
 $app_id = $_REQUEST['app'];
 $fullpath = array();
 $dir = dirname(__FILE__);
 
 
 foreach($language_array as $key_lang=>$name_lang)
 {
  $path = $dir."/uploaded_xml/".$app_id."/";
  
  if(!is_dir($path))
  {
   mkdir($path,0777);
   chmod($path,0755); 
  }
  
  
  $QUERY=mysql_query("select a.process_flag,a.field_id,a.field_name,a.xml_status,b.*,c.process_flag,b.lang_id from app_lang_fieldmaster_new a left join app_lang_translatetxt_new b on a.field_id=b.field_id left join app_lang_user_status c on a.field_id=c.field_id left join app_wise_lang_fields d on a.field_id=d.field_id where a.process_flag='0' and c.process_flag='6' and b.lang_id='".$key_lang."' and a.xml_status='1' and a.module_master_id='1' and d.app_id='".$app_id."' group by 2",$cont);
  
  
  //create the xml document
  $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");

  //create the root element
  $root = $xmlDoc->appendChild(
      $xmlDoc->createElement("resources"));
  
  while($row=mysql_fetch_object($QUERY))
  {
   if($key_lang==9)
   {
    $xml_string = $xmlDoc->createElement( "string",trim($row->translate," "));
    $xml_string->setAttribute( "name",$row->field_name);
    $root->appendChild($xml_string);
   }
   else
   {
    $xml_string = $xmlDoc->createElement( "string",trim(base64_decode($row->translate)," "));
    $xml_string->setAttribute( "name",$row->field_name );
    $root->appendChild($xml_string);
   }
  }

  header("content-type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-15");

  //make the output pretty
  $xmlDoc->formatOutput = true;
  $string = $xmlDoc->saveXML();
  $handle = fopen($path.$name_lang.".xml","w");
  fwrite($handle,$string);
  fclose($handle);
  
  // $string = $xmlDoc->save($path.$name_lang.".xml");
  
  $fullpath[$key_lang] = $path.$name_lang.".xml";
 }
 
 
 ob_clean();
 flush();
 
 //zip file creation
 $zip = new ZipArchive();
 
 //zip file name
 $FilePath = $app_id.".zip";
 
 $full_path_zip = 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."/".$FilePath;
 
 //check if file exists if yes then delete
 if(file_exists(dirname(__FILE__)."/uploaded_xml/".$FilePath)) 
 {
  unlink (dirname(__FILE__)."/uploaded_xml/".$FilePath); 
 }
 
 //open zip file to add files to zip file
 if ($zip->open(dirname(__FILE__)."/uploaded_xml/".$FilePath, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) != TRUE) 
 {
  die ("Could not open archive");
 }
 
 
  //$zip->addFile("file_path","file_name");

 // loop through each file
 foreach($language_array as $key=>$name)
 {
  //add files to zip
  $zip->addFile($fullpath[$key],$name.".xml");
 }
 
 // close and save archive

 $zip->close();
 // header_remove();
 echo $full_path_zip;
 ob_clean();
 flush();
 $filename = dirname(__FILE__)."/uploaded_xml/".$FilePath;
 
 header('Cache-Control: public');  
 header('Content-Description: File Transfer');  
 header('Content-type: application/zip');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment;   filename="'.$filename.'"');
 // echo dirname(__FILE__)."/uploaded_xml/".$FilePath;
 str_replace(".php",".zip",$filename);
 $file_content = file_get_contents($filename);  // To download the ZIP file
 print($file_content); 

}
```

i am creating a zip file which contains some xml files from server, i am adding that xml files to zip and then trying to download the zip but it is downloading .php file. here is my code

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");

    //create the root element
    $root = $xmlDoc->appendChild(
              $xmlDoc->createElement("resources"));

    while($row=mysql_fetch_object($QUERY))
    {
        if($key_lang==9)
        {
            $xml_string = $xmlDoc->createElement( "string",trim($row->translate," "));
            $xml_string->setAttribute( "name",$row->field_name);
            $root->appendChild($xml_string);
        }
        else
        {
            $xml_string = $xmlDoc->createElement( "string",trim(base64_decode($row->translate)," "));
            $xml_string->setAttribute( "name",$row->field_name );
            $root->appendChild($xml_string);
        }
    }

    header("content-type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-15");

    //make the output pretty
    $xmlDoc->formatOutput = true;
    $string = $xmlDoc->saveXML();
    $handle = fopen($path.$name_lang.".xml","w");
    fwrite($handle,$string);
    fclose($handle);

    // $string = $xmlDoc->save($path.$name_lang.".xml");

    $fullpath[$key_lang] = $path.$name_lang.".xml";
}


ob_clean();
flush();

//zip file creation
$zip = new ZipArchive();

//zip file name
$FilePath = $app_id.".zip";

$full_path_zip = 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."/".$FilePath;

//check if file exists if yes then delete
if(file_exists(dirname(__FILE__)."/uploaded_xml/".$FilePath)) 
{
    unlink (dirname(__FILE__)."/uploaded_xml/".$FilePath); 
}

//open zip file to add files to zip file
if ($zip->open(dirname(__FILE__)."/uploaded_xml/".$FilePath, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) != TRUE) 
{
    die ("Could not open archive");
}


    //$zip->addFile("file_path","file_name");

// loop through each file
foreach($language_array as $key=>$name)
{
    //add files to zip
    $zip->addFile($fullpath[$key],$name.".xml");
}

// close and save archive

$zip->close();`
```

here is my download zip file

```
$file_content = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__)."/uploaded_xml/".$FilePath);  // To download the ZIP file
header('Cache-Control: public');  
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');  
header('Content-type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.dirname(__FILE__)."/uploaded_xml/".$FilePath.'"');
echo $file_content;
```

it is downloading .php file with following content

```
PK    ”R—I+ Qý    
 Bulgarian.xml­”ÁnÓ@†ï}Š•ïP¸õ¤B J•Z‰pµ{’X²×ÑzàR ¢¤ŠBHo`ª˜†¤q_aöø×NÔÕ*nkÏÎ73ÿÌlk÷U‰—¤Ò0‘mçáýŽ é'A(ûmçù³½{;Îng«¥(M2åSÚÙ¢•j»^Lm§§B’AêFÝÈ]žå’§fÌ…à+3Âñ£ýà9O[Ûµ{3i˜E‘«WQq–â'32'|Å.jî‚sž ÌÜ   raÞØß%‡©äóM¡ü§«Œ»*ñßK5"|æÀNÌ1|s§Ù¨(³Øí‘§3EnªÉ‹ôà0    ou­f,PzÁ?xÊ—Í¬Hö‡iêÊDº²ïõÉ•®ï©JÅ3ÔqÁPr[ÏRÂOÏ8‡ cü<ÆyC©ûÒû/Â€’ÇÑA¥ä©yî-ù°êà°àíªµô*TèGYp¸¸ËŒó†…íË?H2ýt iÅGƒÖ#üú]~ÇßQ•Ã4XOúÝ+±GOŒl£,vnsÌÊä/øHû6<f‚/ïš6°÷šâÜsä8Z-¦ÔŸ<ß°WX€Úÿ‹²ù"IMêúö)V±lÚu¬Ùf÷=Ï§'¤É×‰:ðºT=µ/Ï¬Äf$°9¹°/Žy_YÊk\k{íAûPK    ”R—I„üa[€  Î     Catalan.xml“ËN+1†÷<E”=—³c1„¸HH ±èa¹‰gj)—ÊI*x(6‡Gè‹áiT!¦=›(·ï÷Ûi®^ƒWkäL)ÎôŸ³­0Úä(ö3ýw~z©¯Ú“†1§Ês{¢T“Ë¹Šp¦;&Œ.¿ðfœëöÎg°flnÎwÄ4¼ªÞ›’c'¡–ƒ˜nçÄÀ
Öà½Z!«Ý¡žÖ³K(['Nà,ä¢Û[êj¦ÍÇ4µbTƒéJe4¹ ...
```

If i change the extension of downloaded file from .php to .zip it is working fine.

Kindly help thanks in advance...

Comment: readfile("$archive_file_name"); after headers insted of print_r() / echo and try once.

Answer (score 2):

> Remove this line:
>   `echo $file_content;`

```
// To download the ZIP file
header('Cache-Control: public');  
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');  
header('Content-type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename="'.dirname(__FILE__)."/uploaded_xml/".$FilePath.'"');
```

Comment: @user7334323, **readfile("$archive_file_name");** after headers insted of print_r() / echo and try once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$file_content = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__)."/uploaded_xml/".$FilePath);  // To download the ZIP file
header('Cache-Control: public');  
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');  
header('Content-type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;   filename="'.dirname(__FILE__)."/uploaded_xml/".$FilePath.'"');
```

Comment: have removed the echo $file_content;

Comment: echo this dirname(__FILE__)."/uploaded_xml/".$FilePath.

Comment: header('Content-type: application/zip');

Comment: if i use echo $file_content it is downloading the .php extension file, and if i rename it to .zip it is working fine... can you tell me what will be the issue

Comment: replace your add this header('Content-type: application/force download '); to add this header('Content-type: application/zip');

Comment: i think you have an issue in $FilePath

Comment: just echo dirname(FILE)."/uploaded_xml/".$FilePath

Comment: and tell me what is it printing?

Comment: your downloading filename is in .php extension so

Comment: $filename=str_replace(".php",".zip",$filename);

Comment: it is printing real path as /var/www/html/domain_name/uploaded_xml/filename.zip

Comment: use this header('Content-type: application/zip');

Comment: don't echo the $file_content;

Comment: print $file_content

Comment: removed echo $file_content

Comment: add print $file_content;

Comment: print $file_content

Comment: print also downloads .php extension

Comment: before print, replace the extension .php with .zip

Comment: still downloading .php file